# dagger2, how can i call @BindsInstance denoted method of SubComponent..?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

please help me! I have a trouble in use of dagger 2.

I want to bind some dependency in runtime not in compile time inside `MainActivity` by using `@Subcomponent.Builder` and `@BindsInstance`

I have an ApplicationComponent and it has a Builder and its @BindsInstance looks working fine. I can use like below

```
DaggerApplicationComponent
    .builder()
    .application(this)
    .build()
    .inject(this)
```

but some trouble came from MainActivity...

below are snippets of codes

[ApplicationComponent]

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
internal interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }
}
```

[ApplicationModule]

```
@Module(
        includes = [
            AndroidInjectionModule::class,
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
            ActivityInjectionModule::class
        ],
        subcomponents = [
            MainComponent::class
        ]
)
internal abstract class ApplicationModule {

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SplashModule::class])
    abstract fun splashActivity(): SplashActivity

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun mainActivity(builder: MainComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>

}
```

[MainComponent]

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = [MainModule::class])
internal interface MainComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>()  {
        @BindsInstance
        abstract fun testClass(mainTestClass: MainTestClass): Builder
    }
}
```

[MainActivity]

```
internal class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//        This works find without runtime injection
//        AndroidInjection.inject(this)

        /**
         *I want to bind some dependency(in this case, MainTestClass) in runtime like below.
         * so that I can use MainTestClass inside MainModule to inject this to other classes.
         * but, for some reason,
         * DaggerMainComponent IS NOT GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY...
         */
        DaggerMainComponent.builder()
                .testClass(MainTestClass())
                .build()
                .inject(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        startActivity(Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java))
    }

}
```

The problem is that I cannot access DaggerMainComponent because the Dagger doesn't generate it automatically.
I am searching for lots of websites to solve this but failed.
Is there any way to make it?

Comment: I have a tutorial with a working example of this:https://dev.to/autonomousapps/the-daggerandroid-missing-documentation-33kj

Comment: @AutonomousApps I've walked through your post. It seems that describes how to pass Context to MainApplicationComponent. but it's Component, not a Subcomponent. I'm looking for the way to pass some dependency to Subcomponent builder. Anyway, thanks for your comment !

Comment: Yes, you're right. I posted my comment before fully reading your post. I've actually been planning a blog post where I discuss your use case, but haven't gotten around to it. I can only sketch out a solution here, but consider that your DaggerMainComponent is a SUBcomponent, and Dagger must provide it itself. You can actually inject subcomponent builders! Do that, and use the injected builder to do what you want. I'll try to write out a full solution this weekend, but let me know if you try this and how it goes.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your use-case? What is `MainTestClass`? Why do you need to determine it at runtime, rather than compile-time? If it relates to tests, as seems the case, why not bind it to the root component?

Comment: @AutonomousApps MainTestClass is just simple POJO concrete class. Please don't mind about the class name. It is not related to Unit Test. Actually, in this sample code that I wrote, You might think It looks like there is no specific reason to use runtime binding. Right, but, In another my real application code lines there are requirements like above case. So, I just want to know if there is any way of Binding in runtime or not with above sample code lines.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it's not related to tests. Nevertheless, a better idea of why you need this would help me help you. You can't use AndroidInjection to inject a subcomponent that has a BindsInstance method, because Dagger will complain that your POJO wasn't provided and is null. You can, however, use constructor injection on a non framework class to inject the subcomponent builder, build the subc, and then stash it somewhere for injecting your activity. Or you could just parcel something over in an intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve what you want, I think. Apologies for not using your particular example, but it was easier to paste in the code I have and know that works from my own IDE. I've added comments on the critical lines. Here's the code:

**Singleton component**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
  AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
  RuntimeBindingModule::class // my addition!
])
interface MainApplicationComponent {

  fun inject(app: MainApplication)

  // my addition!
  fun runtimeBuilder(): RuntimeBindingActivitySubcomponent.Builder

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    fun build(): MainApplicationComponent
    @BindsInstance fun app(app: Context): Builder
  }
}
```

**This binding code is essentially identical to yours.**

```
@Subcomponent
interface RuntimeBindingSubcomponent : AndroidInjector<RuntimeBindingActivity> {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<RuntimeBindingActivity>() {
    @BindsInstance abstract fun bindInt(intVal: Int): Builder
  }
}

@Module(subcomponents = [RuntimeBindingSubcomponent::class])
abstract class RuntimeBindingActivityModule {
  @Binds @IntoMap @ActivityKey(RuntimeBindingActivity::class)
  abstract fun bindInjectorFactory(
    builder: RuntimeBindingActivitySubcomponent.Builder
  ): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Activity>
}
```

**MainApplication**

```
open class MainApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

  // This needs to be accessible to your Activities
  lateinit var component: MainApplication.MainApplicationComponent

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    initDagger()
  }

  private fun initDagger() {
    component = DaggerMainApplicationComponent.builder()
      .app(this)
      .build()
    component.inject(this)
  }
}
```

**RuntimeBindingActivity**

```
class RuntimeBindingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  // I had to use @set:Inject because this is a primitive and we can't use lateinit 
  // on primitives. But for your case, 
  // `@Inject lateinit var mainTestClass: MainTestClass` would be fine
  @set:Inject var intVal: Int = -1

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // And this is how you can get runtime binding
    val subComponent = (application as MainApplication).component.runtimeBuilder()
    with(subComponent) {
      seedInstance(this@RuntimeBindingActivity)
      bindInt(10) // runtime binding
      build()
    }.inject(this)

    Log.d("RuntimeBindingActivity", "intVal = $intVal")

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_runtime_binding)
  }
}
```

It is **critically important** to note that the subcomponent which you generate in this way doesn't get magically stored somewhere by dagger. If you want your late-bound instance to be available for injecting into other classes controlled by your `@PerActivity` scope, you need to manually manage the lifecycle of this subcomponent. Store it somewhere (maybe in your custom Application class), and then you also must set its reference to `null` when your activity is destroyed, or you'll be leaking that activity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would try your practice later. I think it might work but as you mentioned, it looks like I should manage the subcomponents lifecycle. I think I got more knowledge of Dagger 2 because of your help. Thanks!